# How do i save my output array from a loop?

Tags: arrays, matlab, concatenation

I have a loop which outputs variable `A` as an `mx1 matrix (where: m>1)` for each iteration. At the end of the entire loop, `A` will end up as an `mxn matrix`. Although the output is returned as an `mxn` matrix, it however keeps overwriting the results. I have tried so many stuffs (including the ones that have worked for my previous codes) but none seem to work. Nevertheless, i feel the code below should work but i'm not sure where the error is coming from.

```
x_A = NaN(28, 3); % 28=length of A and 3=length of kk
Z = [1,2,4,7];

for kk = 1: numel(Z)
   [A,B,C] = fsave_output(Z, kk)
   x_A     = [x_A(:,kk) A(:,kk)];

   % repeat the line above for B and C

end
```

When i run this, i get the error message: **"Attempted to access x_A(:,3); index out of bounds because size(x_norm)=[28,2]."**. However, the outputs in x_A(:,1) and X_A(:,2) are correct, only that x_A(:,3) doesn't show.

Any ideas/suggestions/help on what i should do here? Many thanks in advance!.

Comment: Are you sure that A is of the same size at every loop iteration? And storing like `x_A     = [x_A; [A]];` slows code a lot, use preallocation.

Comment: Thanks @Gryphon for your response. Well like i said, i have tried many tricks in the book. Also, for the first part of your question; `A` sure has the same size at every iteration.

Comment: In the updated code you resize x_A array every loop iteration, so at kk = 3 you get the error, because at this time x_A is 28x2

Comment: Oh really!, well any advice as to how i can counter this? Thank you!

Comment: `x_A(:,kk) = A;`

Comment: Actually, it is: `x_A(:,kk) = A(:,kk);` that works. I'm wondering how on earth this could have taken me the whole day. Thank you so very much @Gryphon.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of matrices to store before the loop, try

```
Z = [1,2,4,7];
store_A = zeros(numel(Z), m); %m is known length
store_B = zeros(numel(Z), m); %if not known, unroll first iteration of loop
store_С = zeros(numel(Z), m); %or store it in a cell and concatenate after the loop

for kk = 1: numel(Z)
   [store_A(kk,:),store_B(kk,:),store_C(kk,:)] = fsave_output(Z, kk)
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Gryphon. This throws up an error in the function "fsave_output". Nevertheless, i have tried something that seems closer to the expected result. Please see the edited question.